# Is solving the following system of boolean equations NP-hard?

Tags: np-hardness, sat, reductions

I reduced a problem I'm currently working on to the following system of boolean equations:

$$
X_i \iff
\begin{cases}
\bigvee_{B \in A_i} \bigwedge_{k \in B} X_k \\
true \\
false
\end{cases}
$$

Where $|B|>=1$ for all $B \in A_i$ and each $X_i$ has exactly one of these defining equations.

I need to find $X_i$ that satisfies all these equations ($A_i$ are given). I'm wondering if this problem is NP-hard. I couldn't reduce the general boolean satisfiability problem to it yet.

Ideally, I would find an algorithm to solve this problem in polynomial time. If it's NP-hard I guess I have to hope that SAT solvers can solve it reasonably fast.

Thanks!

---

Here's an example:
$$
X_1 \iff true \\
X_2 \iff false \\
X_3 \iff X_4 \\
X_4 \iff X_1 \vee (X_2 \wedge X_3)
$$

Comment: After unit propagation what's left will be monotone, so if it's not visibly unsatisfiable, then the all-true assignment always satisfies it. Or did you mean to allow negations in some places too?

Comment: Can negations not be expressed as follows? To obtain the negation of Xi, create variables Yi (this will be the negation), Ti, Fi. 
Require Fi <=> False, 
Ti <=> True, 
Fi <=> Xi AND Yi, 
Ti <=> Xi OR Yi. 

If this is indeed allowed in your type of set system, I will see if I can write an answer

Comment: The disparity between Joshua Grochow’s and user53923’s comments highlights another ambiguity in the question: for each $i$, does the system include only *one* equation with left-hand side $X_i$, or can there be more of them?

Comment: With $x\lor y \iff\text{True}$ and $x\land y \iff\text{False}$, you get $x$ as the negation of $y$.  This allows you to construct an arbitrary set of clauses over Boolean variables, so that the problem is as hard as SAT.

Comment: They way it's written, I am reading the conditions as saying "each $X_i$ has to be either equivalent to (long formula), or it has to be true, or it has to be false", which is nonsense. What is actually meant by "... or $X_i = \mathrm{True}$ or $X_i = \mathrm{False}$"? Is that just noise that should be deleted?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! I just edited the question to make it clearer. Really appreciate all your help!

Comment: I actually think @JoshuaGrochow's solution should work (input all the false values to see which variables have to be false and then set everything else to true).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Now that the question's been clarified I'll post my previous comment as an answer.]

It's in $\mathsf{P}$. Start with unit propagation. Afterwards, what's left on the right-hand sides will be monotone, so will be satisfied by setting all remaining variables to True.

(If you want to *count* the number of solutions, on the other hand, that might be harder.)

Comment: How is something like $X \iff Y$ monotone?  If $X$ is false, doesn't it force $Y$ to be false?  I agree that the all true assignment works, but this doesn't seem the same as monotonicity.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving: You're right, I should've been more specific that it's what's on the *right-hand sides* that is monotone, and therefore the all true assignment works. (But the point is, to find a satisfying assignment here one doesn't need full monotonicity.) I updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks!